# Mysql connection string error ASP

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I am getting below error while connecting to my sql.
Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'DESKTOP-I6BL7QQ' (using password: NO)

Sample code:`<add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="server=root;user=kunal;database=register;port=3306;password=******;" />`

Answer (score 0):

Connection String.

```
<add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="server=root;uid=kunal;pwd=#######;database=register;" providerName="MySQL.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Install MySQL.

1. MySql.Data
2. MySql.Data.Entity

Link for Nuget Packages:- 
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=MySql.Data&prerel=false